# Simple proof involving standard normal distribution

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions

I have the following exercise:

> Prove that for all $d \in \mathbb{N}$ and all $i,j \in \{1,\dots,d\}$ it holds that $$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} x_i \mathcal{N}_{0,I_{\mathbb{R}^d}}(dx_1,\dots,dx_d) = 0, \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} x_i x_j \mathcal{N}_{0,I_{\mathbb{R}^d}}(dx_1,\dots,dx_d) = \begin{cases} 1 &: i = j \\ 0 &: else \\ \end{cases} $$

where $\mathcal{N}_{0,I_{\mathbb{R}^d}}: \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d) \to [0, \infty]$ is the $d$-dimensional standard normal distribution given by $$\mathcal{N}_{0,I_{\mathbb{R}^d}}(B) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{d/2}} \int_B e^{-\frac{1}{2}||x||^2_{\mathbb{R}^d}} dx$$

The exercise is probably simple, but I have difficulties with the notation as given above, i.e. if the integrals were given as $\int_\mathbb{R} x_i f_X(x) dx$ etc. I would just compute it.

Can someone give me a hint how to tackle the notation?

**Edit after hint**

Ok, with factorizing, splitting the integral and using a Riemann integral I get for all $d \in \mathbb{N}$ and all $i,j \in \{1,\dots,d\}$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x_i \phi(x_i)\mathrm{dx_i} * \prod_{k \neq i} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \phi(x_k)\mathrm{dx_k} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x_i \phi(x_i)\mathrm{dx_i} = \big[-\phi(x_i)\big]_{-\infty}^{\infty} = 0~, 
\end{align}
for the first term and
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x_i \phi(x_i)\mathrm{dx_i} * \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x_j \phi(x_j)\mathrm{dx_j} * \prod_{k \notin \{i,j\}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \phi(x_k)\mathrm{dx_k} = 0 \quad : i \neq j~, \\
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x_i^2 \phi(x_i)\mathrm{dx_i} * \prod_{k \neq i} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \phi(x_k)\mathrm{dx_k} = \big[\Phi(x_i)- x_i\phi(x_i)\big]_{-\infty}^{\infty} = 1 \quad : i = j~,
\end{equation}
for the second term, where $\phi(x) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{1/2}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}$ and in the last equality I assumed that $lim_{x \to \infty}[x \phi(x)] = 0$.

Comment: Replace $\mathbb{R}$ by $\mathbb{R}^d$ (three places).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\mathcal{N}_{0,I_{\mathbb{R}^d}}$ has density
$$
\mathbb{R}^d\ni x=(x_1,\ldots,x_d)\mapsto \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{d/2}}\mathrm{e}^{-\tfrac12 \|x\|^2}
$$
with respect to the $d$-dimensional Lebesgue measure $\lambda_d$, one has
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(x)\,\mathcal{N}_{0,I_{\mathbb{R}^d}}(\mathrm d x)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{d/2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(x)\mathrm{e}^{-\tfrac12 \| x\|^2}\,\lambda_d(\mathrm dx)
$$
for any integrable function $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! A question: Is it true that I now can equate the last expression with a normal Riemann integral by setting \begin{align} \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{d/2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(x)\mathrm{e}^{-\tfrac12 \| x\|^2}\,\lambda_d(\mathrm dx)  &= lim_{(a^d,b^d) \to (-\infty^d, \infty^d)} \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{d/2}}\int_{a^d}^{b^d} f(x)\mathrm{e}^{-\tfrac12 \| x\|^2} \mathrm{dx} \\ &= \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{d/2}}\int_{-\infty^d}^{\infty^d} f(x)\mathrm{e}^{-\tfrac12 \| x\|^2} \mathrm{dx} ? \end{align}

Comment: You can if the function you're integrating is Riemann-integrable (so especially if the function is continuous). However, the integrals you're interested factorizes, i.e. $f(x)=g_1(x_1)\cdots g_d(x_d)$ and hence you may split up the integrals using Fubini's theorem.

Comment: Ok, I tried to prove it given your information. Is it correct?

Comment: @mwater: Looks like you're using $\phi$ to mean $\phi(x)=(2\pi)^{-1/2}\mathrm{e}^{-x^2/2}$. If that's the case, then it looks fine to me. That $\lim_{x\to\infty} xe^{-x^2/2}=0$ can be seen by using L'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: Yes that is the case, I added it to my post. Great, thank you very much for your help, learned a lot today!